# ATCTContent created with wrong id and title

Tags: field, plone, archetypes

I've made an add-on with several ATCTContent, all created with `paster addcontent contenttype`. All but one, `GearContent` work as expected. Only when I create instances of GearContent they receive names like gear, gear-1, etc. ignoring the title. In default view, the H1 tag is always 'Gear' but the title bellow it is right.

Trying to change the ids and titles on the folder content view doesn't do anything. There's no error message.

Same thing with the catalog. GearContent's `Title` metadata is 'Gear' for all instances. It works for all other types.

GearContent is only addable inside GearFolder. Other contents have similar restrictions and work fine. I'm using plone 4.0.4.

What can I do to make new instances get the title right?

Below content/gearcontent.py:

```
 """Definition of the Gear Content content type
 """

 from zope.interface import implements

 from Products.Archetypes import atapi
 from Products.ATContentTypes.content import base
 from Products.ATContentTypes.content import schemata

 # -*- Message Factory Imported Here -*-
 from levity7.gears import gearsMessageFactory as _

 from levity7.gears.interfaces import IGearContent
 from levity7.gears.config import PROJECTNAME

 GearContentSchema = schemata.ATContentTypeSchema.copy() + atapi.Schema((

     # -*- Your Archetypes field definitions here ... -*-

     atapi.StringField(
         'title',
         storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
         widget=atapi.StringWidget(
             label=_(u"Title"),
             description=_(u"Name for this content."),
         ),
         required=True,
     ),


     atapi.ReferenceField(
         'activities',
         storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
         widget=atapi.ReferenceWidget(
             label=_(u"Adventure Activities"),
             description=_(u"Select all activities that apply to this content."),
         ),
         required=True,
         relationship='gearcontent_activities',
         allowed_types=('Gear Activity'), # specify portal type names here ('Example Type',)
         multiValued=True,
     ),


     atapi.ReferenceField(
         'category',
         storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
         widget=atapi.ReferenceWidget(
             label=_(u"Category"),
             description=_(u"Select a category for this content."),
         ),
         required=True,
         relationship='gearcontent_category',
         allowed_types=('Gear Category'), # specify portal type names here ('Example Type',)
         multiValued=False,
     ),


     atapi.ImageField(
         'image',
         storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
         widget=atapi.ImageWidget(
             label=_(u"Image"),
             description=_(u"A picture of this content."),
         ),
         validators=('isNonEmptyFile'),
     ),


     atapi.StringField(
         'imageLink',
         storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
         widget=atapi.StringWidget(
             label=_(u"Image Link"),
             description=_(u"An URL to the image of this content."),
         ),
         validators=('isURL'),
     ),


     atapi.TextField(
         'description',
         storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
         widget=atapi.RichWidget(
             label=_(u"Description"),
             description=_(u"Description for the content."),
         ),
         required=True,
     ),


     atapi.StringField(
         'reviewLink',
         storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
         widget=atapi.StringWidget(
             label=_(u"Review Link"),
             description=_(u"Link to Review page."),
         ),
         validators=('isURL'),
     ),


     atapi.StringField(
         'diyLink',
         storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
         widget=atapi.StringWidget(
             label=_(u"DIY Link"),
             description=_(u"Link to DIY page."),
         ),
         validators=('isURL'),
     ),


     atapi.TextField(
         'commentary',
         storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
         widget=atapi.TextAreaWidget(
             label=_(u"commentary"),
             description=_(u"commentarys for the content. These will not be displayed."),
         ),
     ),


     atapi.TextField(
         'purchaseHtml',
         storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
         widget=atapi.TextAreaWidget(
             label=_(u"Purchase HTML Code"),
             description=_(u"HTML used to display or add this item to the Cart."),
         ),
     ),


     atapi.IntegerField(
         'score',
         storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
         widget=atapi.IntegerWidget(
             label=_(u"Life This Value"),
             description=_(u"Initial value of 'Life This'"),
         ),
         default=_(u"0"),
         validators=('isInt'),
     ),


 ))

 # Set storage on fields copied from ATContentTypeSchema, making sure
 # they work well with the python bridge properties.

 GearContentSchema['title'].storage = atapi.AnnotationStorage()
 GearContentSchema['description'].storage = atapi.AnnotationStorage()

 schemata.finalizeATCTSchema(GearContentSchema, moveDiscussion=False)


 class GearContent(base.ATCTContent):
     """Gear Content"""
     implements(IGearContent)

     meta_type = "GearContent"
     schema = GearContentSchema

     title = atapi.ATFieldProperty('title')
     description = atapi.ATFieldProperty('description')

     # -*- Your ATSchema to Python Property Bridges Here ... -*-
     title = atapi.ATFieldProperty('title')

     activities = atapi.ATReferenceFieldProperty('activities')

     category = atapi.ATReferenceFieldProperty('category')

     image = atapi.ATFieldProperty('image')

     imageLink = atapi.ATFieldProperty('imageLink')

     description = atapi.ATFieldProperty('description')

     reviewLink = atapi.ATFieldProperty('reviewLink')

     diyLink = atapi.ATFieldProperty('diyLink')

     commentary = atapi.ATFieldProperty('commentary')

     purchaseHtml = atapi.ATFieldProperty('purchaseHtml')

     score = atapi.ATFieldProperty('score')


 atapi.registerType(GearContent, PROJECTNAME)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove your "title" field. It's already defined in ATContentTypeSchema. You're effectively re-implementing it, but without the baseline functionality like automatic content object naming. Yours is masking the one defined in Archetypes.

Comment: Thanks! The curious thing is that other contents have a title field and haven't the same problem. I use it to change the label from 'Title' to 'Name'.

Comment: Do that after building the schema: GearContentSchema['title'].widget.label =_(u"Name")

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the field `category`. It seems that's a reserved name. (in the above it appears 'categoty'; it was a typo).

Comment: SteveM was right. The `category` field name wasn't the problem.